# Class member functions not compiling

Tags: c++, function, oop, g++, member

I decided to write my own Vector class for my library but when I try to compile it using `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -O a.cpp -c -o a.o` and read the symbols from the output file using `nm a.o` I don't see any member functions that I wrote for that class and when I try to link it with a program that uses them I get `undefined reference to` errors.
Here is the a.h file:

```
template<typename T> class Vector {
    private:
        int vsize;
        const int maxsize=2147483647;
        T* array;
    public:
        Vector();
        ~Vector();
        bool push_back(T t);
        bool pop_back(T* t);
        bool replace(int element, T t);
        bool resize(int newsize);
        bool getP(int element, T* t);
        bool clear();
        T* getArray();
        int size();
        T operator[](int n);
};
```

And the a.cpp file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "a.h"

template<typename T> Vector<T>::Vector() {
    vsize=0;
    array=(T*)malloc(sizeof(T)*vsize);
}
template<typename T> Vector<T>::~Vector() {
    free(array);
}
template<typename T> bool Vector<T>::push_back(T t) {
    if(resize(vsize+1))
        return 1;
    array[vsize-1] = t;
    return 0;
}
template<typename T> bool Vector<T>::pop_back(T* t) {
    *t = array[vsize-1];
    return resize(vsize-1);
}
/*
    Other member function definitons...
*/
```

I'm using g++ 5.4.0 and nm 2.26.1

Comment: Are you asking why you cannot split a template class into header file and definition file like non-template classes, or is there more to your question?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Kinda. And why I don't see any symbols.

Comment: there is nothing to compile, its just a template

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl

Comment: @tobi303 So how do i compile it?

Comment: stricly speaking you dont compile templates and you cannot have templates in source files

Comment: Okay it compiles now :)